# DateTime conversion to FileTimeUtc

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a DateTime variable defined as DateTime.Now. I need to "convert" this to FileTimeUtc. I must be completely misunderstanding this because I assumed this would work:

```
DateTime RunTime;
RunTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc();
```

But I get the error cannot implicitly convert type long to system.datetime.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc.aspx) returns a long, not a `DateTime`.  From the documentation:

> A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). Windows uses a file time to record when an application creates, accesses, or writes to a file.

This should be:

```
long runTime;
runTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc();
```

If you just want the current Coordinated Universal Time, and not the *Windows file time*, you can use:

```
DateTime runTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
```

See [UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

`ToFileTimeUtc()` returns a long that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc.aspx

Implicit casting of long to datetime is not supported by the .net framework.

If you want a date as UTC use `ToUniversalTime()`
or to get now as UTC use `UtcNow`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx